# Is there is any way to remove View All link from App launcher

Tags: configuration

I want to remove View all from App launcher , without effecting anything. If yes please help me out
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no 'setting' to hide **View All** link at this time. Because, when you click this link, it will take you to **All Items** and as per the product team's response on this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNbDQAU), you cannot hide the "All Items" label at this time

An admin can however hide all of the "Items" in "All Items".

[image]

To hide items from the App Launcher individually, one should follow the steps below

1. Go to Setup
2. In the Quick Find bar, search for Profiles.
3. Select the Profile you want to remove items for.
4. Click Object Settings in the App Settings.
5. Select the Object Name you want to remove items for in the App Launcher.
6. Click Edit.
7. Change the Tab Settings picklist value to Tab Hidden.
8. Click Save.
9. Click Object Settings in the breadcrumbs.